# Word file converted to XPS makes hyperlinks inactive

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, xps

I have a `WPF application` in which I show a `word document` to user in `XPS` format. 
I use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. Code is below

But the hyperlinks in the word file are inactive(not clickable and don't take me to where they are linked to). How do I fix this ?

```
public static XpsDocument ConvertWordToXps(string wordFilename, string xpsFilename)
{
    // Create a WordApplication and host word document 
    var wordApp = new Application();
    wordApp.Application.Visible = false;
    wordApp.Documents.Open(wordFilename);

    // To Invisible the word document 
    wordApp.Application.Visible = false;

    // Minimize the opened word document 
    wordApp.WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;

    Document doc = wordApp.ActiveDocument;

    doc.SaveAs(xpsFilename, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXPS);

    var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(xpsFilename, FileAccess.Read);
    return xpsDocument;

}
```

Comment: are you perhaps losing any of the formatting that might cause this issue.. are you able to view the document correctly less the links not showing up correctly..? also the `hyper links` are converted to `Targeted Format` here is a forum with some `Q/A` https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/492a79e5-5333-4fdb-888b-a23020374a8d/how-to-load-an-xps-document-into-documentviewer-using-an-xps-file-using-a-stream?forum=wpf

Comment: I am using `DocumentViewer` to look at XPS and it does shows the content with correct formatting. Only the hyperlinks are working.

Comment: your question states the opposite it states that the HyperLinks are lost.. fix your question please

Comment: Sorry I meant to say hyperlinks are "not" working.

Answer (score 1):

Had to write an event handler for `DocumentViewer` object (documentviewWord)  for handling hyperlinks

```
private void link_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

And in the View Constructor

```
documentviewWord.AddHandler(Hyperlink.RequestNavigateEvent, new RequestNavigateEventHandler(link_RequestNavigate));
```

Comment: Hi @coolshashi, the link_RequestNavigate is not fired..may i know how you make this works?